# Array of Codable structs possibly decoded from JSON data object

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have this piece of code:

```
struct NoteRecord: Codable {

let id: String
let title: String
let detail: String?
let dueDate: String?

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id, title, detail, dueDate
}}
```

and parsing part:

```
do {
     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     let note = try decoder.decode(NoteRecord.self, from: data)

      } catch let err {
          print("Error occured:", err)
      }
```

Is there any way to use this when REST API returns an array of objects to decode the data correctly as array of structs?

Comment: Just remove the `let theNote = …` line. `note` will be initialised if the data is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use this:

```
do {
     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     let notes = try decoder.decode([NoteRecord].self, from: data)

      } catch let err {
          print("Error occured:", err)
      }
```

If you use  `[YourCodableStruct].self` you are parsing the array.  If you use `YourCodableStruct.self` you are parsing the struct.

Comment: super easy, thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can implement another struct to hold the array.

```
struct NoteRecords: Codable {
    var list: [NoteRecord] // You should change the var name and coding keys
}
```

And parse it like

```
let note = try decoder.decode(NoteRecords.self, from: data)
```

I hope this helps.